# Export Pivot Table and Source data to another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I need to export a pivot table and its source data to another Excel Workbook. I have written this function to do it:

```
Public Function SaveASSheets (sheetsArray As Variant, destination As String)    
    Sheets(sheetsArray).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs destination, 50
    ActiveWorkbook.Close    
End Function
```

sheetsArray is an array with PivotTable and PivotTable source data worksheets
destination is a full path where I want the new Excel file (path + fine name + extension (.xlsb))

The problem I have when I execute this code is new pivot table saved in a new file in destination folder is pointing to the old pivot table source data, instead of using the source data tab I have copied with it.
Data source range in the Name Manager that I use for the old pivot table exist in both files (new and old) but the pivot table in the new file is pointing to the data source range in the old file.

I have tried to reassign new pivot table data source but I got an error:

> "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources, Chose less data or close other applications"

This is my the code:

```
Public Function SaveASSheets(sheetsArray As Variant, destination As String, Optional pivotTableRange As Range)    
    Sheets(sheetsArray).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs destination, 50
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each Pivot In Sheet.PivotTables
            If Not pivotTableRange Is Nothing Then
                Pivot.SourceData = pivotTableRange
            End If
            Pivot.RefreshTable
            Pivot.Update            
        Next
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Close    
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s first review the procedures you posted:

Both procedures create a new workbook using a group of worksheets copied from the active workbook.

The objects in the copied worksheets retain all their original properties, `PivotTable.SourceData` among them, so the `PivotTables` copied are still pointing to the “source workbook”.

In the second procedure your attempt to set the `PivotTable.SourceData` to the “Input Range” recieved by the procedure. It fails as the application is trying to create in the “New Workbook” a `PivotCache` pointing to the “Source Workbook”. However, even if this operation ends successfully, it will not achieve its purpose as the “Input Range” is still addressing the “Source Workbook”. Additionally, note that the procedure closes the workbook without saving it, so if the objective was achieved it would have been lost.

Suggest also to always declare the variables having this line in all modules will assist you with this good practice.

```
Option Explicit
```

It can be part of the standard VBA settings. In the Excel VBA application menu select: `Tools\Options` in the dialog box tab: Editor, check the “Require Variable Declaration” option

[image]

*This solution propose two methods to achieve the:*

**Objective**: Create a new workbook containing a set of worksheets from the active workbook. This set contains worksheets with `PivotTables` having a common `SourceData` that resides in a worksheet also included in the set.

**Procedures arguments**:

`aShtSrc`   `As Variant`    Array containing the names of the worksheets to be included in the new workbook

`sFullPath` `As String` Path and Filename of the new workbook

- **Method 1**: Copy set of worksheets from source workbook into a new workbook and change `PivotTables` in new workbook to a new `PivotCache` pointing to the `DataSource` in the new workbook.

  ```
  Sub Ptb_Copy_To_NewWbk_And_Change_DataSource(aShtSrc As Variant, sFullPath As String)
  Dim WbkSrc As Workbook, WbkNew As Workbook
  Dim Wsh As Worksheet, Pch As PivotCache, Ptb As PivotTable
  Dim sPtbSrc As String
  Dim blPtDone As Boolean
  Dim blAppDisplayAlerts As Boolean

      Rem Set Application Properties
      blAppDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.EnableEvents = False

      Rem Set Source Workbook
      Set WbkSrc = ThisWorkbook

      Rem Get PivotTable Source Data
      sPtbSrc = Empty
      For Each Wsh In WbkSrc.Worksheets(aShtSrc)
          On Error Resume Next
          sPtbSrc = Wsh.PivotTables(1).SourceData
          On Error GoTo 0
          If sPtbSrc <> Empty Then Exit For
      Next

      Rem Copy Sheets to Create New Workbook
      WbkSrc.Sheets(aShtSrc).Copy
      Set WbkNew = ActiveWorkbook

      Rem Save New Workbook (overwrites existing workbook)
      Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
      WbkNew.SaveAs Filename:=sFullPath, FileFormat:=xlExcel12
      Application.DisplayAlerts = 1

      Rem Create PivotCache in New Workbook
      Set Pch = WbkNew.PivotCaches.Create( _
          SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
          SourceData:=sPtbSrc, _
          Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

      Rem Change PivotCache to 1st PivotTable in New Workbook
      For Each Wsh In WbkNew.Worksheets
          For Each Ptb In Wsh.PivotTables
              Ptb.ChangePivotCache Pch
              blPtDone = True
              Exit For
          Next
          If blPtDone Then Exit For
      Next

      Rem Change PivotCache to Reamining PivotTables in New Workbook
      For Each Wsh In WbkNew.Worksheets
          For Each Ptb In Wsh.PivotTables
              Ptb.CacheIndex = Pch.Index
      Next: Next

      Rem Refresh PivotTables, Save & Close New Workbbok
      Pch.Refresh
      WbkNew.Close SaveChanges:=True
      WbkSrc.Activate

      Rem Set Application Properties
      Application.DisplayAlerts = blAppDisplayAlerts
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.EnableEvents = True

  End Sub
  ```
- **Method 2**: Copy source workbook as new workbook, then open new workbook and delete in new workbook the worksheets not included in list of worksheets received.

  ```
  Sub Wbk_Copy_To_NewWbk_SelectedSheets(aShtSrc As Variant, sFullPath As String)
  Dim WbkSrc As Workbook, WbkNew As Workbook
  Dim Wsh As Worksheet
  Dim blShtDelete As Boolean
  Dim vItm As Variant
  Dim blAppDisplayAlerts As Boolean

  Rem Set Application Properties
  blAppDisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  Rem Set Source Workbook
  Set WbkSrc = ThisWorkbook

  Rem Save as New Workbook
  WbkSrc.SaveCopyAs (sFullPath)

  Rem Open New Workbook
  Set WbkNew = Workbooks.Open(sFullPath)

  Rem Delete Other Worksheets in New Workbook
  For Each Wsh In WbkNew.Worksheets
      blShtDelete = True
      For Each vItm In aShtSrc
          If Wsh.Name = vItm Then
              blShtDelete = False
              Exit For
      End If: Next
      If blShtDelete Then Wsh.Delete
  Next

  Rem Save & Close New Workbbok
  WbkNew.Close SaveChanges:=True
  WbkSrc.Activate

  Rem Set Application Properties
  Application.DisplayAlerts = blAppDisplayAlerts
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much @EEM for both methods. I have tried the the first one, and it works perfectly when there is just 1 pivot table to copy in the new excel. If there are more than 1, I got always this error: "Run-time erro 5: Invalid procedure call or argument" in this line: " Ptb.ChangePivotCache Pch " when the code is trying to set up the second pivot table. Ptb has the correct name of Pivot Table and Pch has the correct arguments (Type, SourceData and Version). Doy you know why? Thanks again!

Comment: Need more info to figure out what the problem is: 1) There are more that one worksheet with PivotTables?, 2) Do you have at least one worksheet with more than one PivotTable?, 3) Are all these PivotTables pointing to the same `SourceData` are in the same worksheet?, 4) What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: To fix that error, I have moved `Set Pch` code to the `For Each Ptb In Wsh.PivotTables` loop

Comment: Thank you very much @EEM. My source excel spreadsheet has 7 worksheets with pivot tables (1 pivot table per sheet) pointing to the same SourceData (range). I need to export all of them and the data source tab. To fix that error, I have moved `Set Pch` code into the `For Each Ptb In Wsh.PivotTables` loop.

Comment: @ATorre Though moving `Set Pch` code into the `For Each Ptb In Wsh.PivotTables` loop, seems to fixed the error, that is not correct, as that is actually creating a new `PivotCache` for each `PivotTable`. This is not efficient and will certainly lead to errors as users will have to refresh `PivotTables` one by one contrary to what’s Excel expected behavior. Additionally, users may think that because one `PivotTable` is updated all of them also are. I updated the procedure and now still creating only one `PivotCache` and it assigns this `PivotCache` to all `PivotTables`. Pls use revised code.

Comment: thank for the quick response. I totally agree with you. My code was not efficient. I have tested the new version of your method 1 and it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Most welcome, glad it serves you and that you appreciate efficiency. Looking forward to you next question...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that makes a copy of the whole spreadsheet in the new location and deletes the unnecessary tabs

This is the the function:

```
Public Function SaveASSheets(sheetsArray As Variant, destination As String)

   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs destination, 50
   For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      doNotDelete = False
        For Each element In sheetsArray
          If element = Sheet.Name Then
              doNotDelete = True
          End If
      Next
      If Not doNotDelete Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      End If
  Next
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Function
```

I know it is not very nice solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying both the pivot table and the source, why not just update the source of the pivot table in the new workbook to match that of the old. Assuming your sheet naming is the same, use the code below.

```
WkShtIndex = 0
For Each WkSht In NewWB.Worksheets
    WkShtIndex = WkShtIndex + 1
    PTIndex = 0
    For Each PTable In WkSht.PivotTables
        PTIndex = PTIndex + 1
        PTable.SourceData = MasterWkBk.Sheets(NewWB.Worksheets(WkShtIndex).Name).PivotTables(PTIndex).SourceData
        PTable.RefreshTable
    Next PTable
Next WkSht
```